# Troubleshooting Communication Issues with Python WebSocket Client

Tags: python, websocket

I'm attempting to create a Python WebSocket Client to connect to t2tmud. As I'm relatively new to both Python and WebSocket technology, I sought assistance from ChatGPT for the coding process.

The t2tmud server has its own web client that utilizes WebSockets, suggesting that it should be compatible with WebSockets in various programming languages. You can find more information about it here: https://t2tmud.org/connect.php.

The WebSocket URI for the server is: wss://t2tmud.org/8080.

I've successfully developed a Python WebSocket server, with ChatGPT's help, for debugging my client. Here's the server code:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
import random
import string

# Create a set to store connected clients
connected_clients = set()

async def echo(websocket, path):
    # Add the client to the set of connected clients
    connected_clients.add(websocket)

    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            # Just echo back the received message to the sender
            await websocket.send(f"server responds: {message}")
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
        pass
    finally:
        # Remove the client from the set when the connection is closed
        connected_clients.remove(websocket)

async def send_random_messages():
    while True:
        # Generate a random message (e.g., a random string of 10 characters)
        random_message = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10))
        
        # Send the random message to all connected clients
        for client in connected_clients:
            try:
                await client.send(f"Random message from server: {random_message}")
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
                # Remove the client from the set if the connection is closed
                connected_clients.remove(client)
        
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))  # Send a message every 1 to 5 seconds

# Create an asyncio event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Start the WebSocket server on localhost, port 8765
start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8765)

# Run the event loop
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)

# Start sending random messages
loop.create_task(send_random_messages())

# Run the event loop forever
loop.run_forever()
```

Additionally, ChatGPT assisted me in creating a Python WebSocket client for testing purposes, and here's the code for that:

```py
import websockets
import asyncio
import aioconsole

async def receive_messages(websocket):
    try:
        while True:
            response = await websocket.recv()
            print(response)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
        print("WebSocket connection closed gracefully.")
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError as e:
        print(f"WebSocket connection closed with error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred while receiving messages: {e}")

async def send_messages(websocket):
    while True:
        message = await aioconsole.ainput("")
        if message.lower() == 'exit':
            await websocket.close()  # Close the WebSocket before exiting the loop
            break
        await websocket.send(message)

async def main():
    uri = 'wss://t2tmud.org/8080'
    # uri = 'ws://localhost:8765'

    try:
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
            # Run the receive_messages and send_messages tasks concurrently
            await asyncio.gather(
                receive_messages(websocket),
                send_messages(websocket)
            )

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
        print("Exiting mudClient")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        if websocket.open:
            await websocket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The server and client work seamlessly together; the server periodically sends random messages and echoes any messages from the client. This assures me that the client can send and receive messages to/from the server concurrently, meeting my requirements.

However, when I use my Python WebSocket client to connect to the t2tmud WebSocket server, I encounter the following issue:

1. The client successfully connects.
2. The server sends the login-screen message.
3. The client sends a message (any message).
4. There's no response from the server; it's as if the server never receives the message from the client, or the client is unable to receive the server's response.

I considered the possibility of an incompatibility between Python WebSockets and JavaScript WebSockets, but when I developed a JavaScript WebSocket client and tested it on my Python WebSocket server, it worked without any issues.

Here's the JavaScript WebSocket client code that I used for testing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebSocket Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // JavaScript WebSocket client code goes here
        // const uri = 'ws://localhost:8765';
        const uri = 'wss://t2tmud.org/8080';

        const socket = new WebSocket(uri); // Replace with your WebSocket server URL

        socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
            console.log('Connected to the WebSocket server');
            socket.send('Hello, server!');
        });

        socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
            console.log('Received message from server:', event.data);

            // Check if the message is a Blob
            if (event.data instanceof Blob) {
                // Handle the Blob here
                event.data.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
                    // Assuming the binary data in the Blob is text encoded in UTF-8
                    const textDecoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
                    const decodedText = textDecoder.decode(buffer);

                    // Process the decoded text as needed
                    console.log('Received a Blob message (decoded text):', decodedText);
                });
            } else {
                // Handle non-Blob messages
                console.log('Received a non-Blob message:', event.data);
            }
        });

        socket.addEventListener('close', (event) => {
            if (event.wasClean) {
                console.log(`Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code}, reason=${event.reason}`);
            } else {
                console.error('Connection abruptly closed');
            }
        });

        socket.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
            console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
        });

        function sendMessage(message) {
            if (socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                socket.send(message);
            } else {
                console.error('WebSocket not open. Cannot send message.');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The t2tmud server sends the first messages as a Blob, at least the javascript websockets client tells me so. I don't know if the python websocket client recieves a Blob or not.

This behavior suggests that there may be an issue with the t2tmud WebSocket server. I'd appreciate your assistance in troubleshooting this problem.

**Update**:
I tried creating a python telnet client (see code below) and it seems to work flawlessly with the t2tmud server. Could this mean there's something wrong with the server's websockets settings?

```py
import telnetlib
import threading

# Define the server information
HOST = "t2tmud.org"
PORT = 9999  # Telnet port

# Create a Telnet client
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT)

def receive_messages():
    while True:
        try:
            data = tn.read_some()
            print(data.decode("utf-8"), end="")
        except EOFError:
            print("Connection closed by remote host.")
            break

def send_messages():
    while True:
        message = input()
        tn.write(message.encode("utf-8") + b"\n")

# Create threads for sending and receiving
receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_messages)
send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_messages)

# Start the threads
receive_thread.start()
send_thread.start()

# Wait for threads to finish (you can use a signal to gracefully exit)
receive_thread.join()
send_thread.join()

# Close the Telnet connection
tn.close()
```